# How to import .js that imported .json from html

Tags: javascript, json

I am not an English-speaking citizen, I am not good at English but I did best.

I am trying to import a js file that imported json from html

.js

```
import JSON from '../json/menu.json';

(function () {
  function parseMenu(ul, menu) {
    for (var i=0;i<menu.length;i++) {
      if(menu.sub == null) {
        menu.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a.id > b.id ? -1 : a.id > b.id ? 1 : 0;
        });
      }
      var li=$(ul).append('<li><a href="'+menu[i].link+'">'+menu[i].name+'</a></li>');
      if (menu[i].sub!=null) {
        var subul=$('<ul id="submenu'+menu[i].link+'"></ul>');
        $(li).append(subul);
        parseMenu($(subul), menu[i].sub);
      }
    }
  }
  var menu=$('#menu');
  parseMenu(menu, JSON);
});
```

.json form

```
[ {
     {
     },
     {
     }
   },
   {
     {
     },
     {
     }
   },
   {
   }
]
```

I tried like

```
<script type="module" src="../js/left.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="../json/menu.json"></script>
```

in html

But I get the following error
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/json". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
in .json

I solved it.

First. Changed name of variable. JSON to menus

Second. Deleted `<script type="module" src="../js/left.mjs"></script>`

Last. Changed `import JSON from '../json/menu.json';` to `import menus from '../json/menus.json' assert { type: "json" };`

Comment: You can't import JSON with a script tag. You can't import it with Javascript either.

Comment: You can also use `fetch`.

Answer (score 25):

My guess is you are actually trying to use the `.js` as src in this part:

```html
<script type="module" src="../json/menu.json"></script>
```

Chrome currently supports https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-assertions. This allows you to tell the browser that you are importing a json file:

```js
import JSON from '../json/menu.json' assert { type: "json" };
```

By the way you shouldn't use `JSON` as the name of variable because it is a built-in object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: I solved the problem thanks to you. When I use "assert" I get error " ; expected." There is no problem with the result, but is it okay to ignore the error?

Comment: Most javascript/typescript editors don't support the assertion syntax yet, so you will see this error highlighted when coding. However chrome supports it so it runs properly.

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me the way I wanted it to work;
[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

const { default: jsonData } = await import("./data.json", { assert: { type: "json" } })

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.