# How can I display json data on the html using script.js?

Tags: javascript, html

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
    import demo from './data.json'
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = demo;
    console.log(demo)
```

Error in the console:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/json". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

JSON data locates near script.js in the same directory

How can I display JSON data on the HTML using script.js?

Comment: Assuming that code doesn't throw an error (which I'd expect it to, but which you haven't mentioned), your question is really at the level where you should be [looking for a tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) rather than asking here.

Comment: Re edit: You've added `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = demo`. What's the problem with that? Please read [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.tutorialstonight.com/display-json-data-in-html-page#:~:text=To%20display%20the%20JSON%20data%20in%20a%20table%20we%20will,name'%20and%20'marks'.

Comment: Re latest edit: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69548822/how-to-import-js-that-imported-json-from-html

Answer (score -1):

You can display JSON data on the HTML using something like this, accessing the data from the imported ./data.json file (If the JSON data is located in the same JavaScript file, you can simply assign the data to a variable and access it from there.) and rendering it, your code is correct but need JSON.stringify(demo) the data.

For example, you can use the document.getElementById() method to select your  with id="demo" and then set its innerHTML property to the JSON data.

```js
const demo = {
"name": "John",
"age": 30,
"city": "New York"
};

const demoDiv = document.getElementById("demo");

demoDiv.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(demo);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

This will convert the JSON data to a string and display it

cheers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use JQuery.

```
<button onclick="showList()">Show List</button>

<script>
  function showList(){
    fetch("./data.json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => createList(data));
  }
  
  function createList(data) {
    //code to process here
  }
</script>
```

My Source: https://www.tutorialstonight.com/display-json-data-in-html-page

Comment: What about this code isn't working?

Comment: It's 2023, I wouldn't recommend jQuery for this task. It doesn't make anything here easier than native browser functions, so its just a big pile of bloat. That said, despite your recommendation, you don't actually take your own advice in your code example. Your code example then reproduces the code the OP *already has* just in a completely different way and *entirely* fails to address the thing that the question is asking about.